# SELECT name of table if table is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, subquery

I have table with names of tables...

I need to select only that tables that are empty.

For this I've tried to write CURSOR.

```
DECLARE @Footprint VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT '[' + [SchemaName] + '].[FootprintBuildState]'
FROM [dbo].[vwAgencySchemas]

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Footprint
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --CHECK IF Table IS EMPTY (UNCORRECT)
    SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @Footprint + ' FROM ' + @Footprint + ' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @Footprint+ ') '
    EXEC (@query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Footprint
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

This is what I have, but I can't write correct query to select name of empty table

I get Error

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '_test12345678910111213141'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '_test12345678910111213141'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget that cursor - you can *easily* do this with just a simple, single `SELECT` statement - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.YourNamesTable tbl ON t.Name = tbl.TableName
WHERE 
    p.Rows = 0
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Comment: @demo: **why?!?!** `HAVING` should be applied only to **aggregated** columns that use `SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG` etc. - none of my columns use an aggregate, so **no**, there's no need for `HAVING` ...